# What happens to a thread when the original class goes out of scope

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I simplified the example below for the sake of clarity, but I came across this in a live production program and I cannot see how it would be working!

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Counter foo = new Counter();
        ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(foo.Count);
        Thread thread = new Thread(job);
        thread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Main terminated");
    }
}

public class Counter
{
    public void Count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Other thread: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Counter terminated");
    }
}
```

The main routine starts the counter thread and the main routine terminates. The counter thread carries on regardless giving the following output.

```
Main terminated    
Other thread: 0
Other thread: 1
Other thread: 2
Other thread: 3
Other thread: 4
Other thread: 5   
Other thread: 6
Other thread: 7    
Other thread: 8    
Other thread: 9
Counter terminated
```

My example program demonstrates that although the calling class no longer exists, the thread survives to completion. However, my understanding is that once a class is out of scope, its resources will eventually be tidied up by garbage collection.

In my real life scenario, the thread does a mass Emailing lasting 1-2 hours. My question is "Would garbage collection eventually kill off the thread or will GC know that the thread is still processing"? Would my Emailing thread always run to completion or is there a danger it will terminate abnormally?

Comment: *However, my understanding is that once a class is out of scope, its resources will eventually be tidied up by garbage collection.* Threads are a special case... They carry the `Thread` objects "inside" themselves, in the `Thread.CurrentThread`, **and** their current running method is considered to be a GC Root (so a starting point for the GC to discover if an object still has references)... But yes, it is a circular reasoning.

Comment: Classes don't go out of scope. Objects don't go out of scope. Variables go out of scope (which is easy to understand - all it means is the variable doesn't exist any more. If the variable is a reference, it doesn't do anything to the object it refers to).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [System.Threading.Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

> It is not necessary to retain a reference to a Thread object once you have started the thread. The thread continues to execute until the thread procedure is complete.

So even if the `Thread` object is unreferenced, the thread will still run.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the documentation for [System.Threading.Thread.IsBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If a thread isn't a background thread, it will keep the application from shutting down until it's done.

Comment: The isBackground explains it.  When I set it to true, the program immediately terminates as I was expecting.  Thanks for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: @MortimerCat That has nothing to do with garbage collection.  It's an *entirely* separate behavior.  The object that the thread's entry point is running on isn't being collected, rather the entire process is being torn down because there are no active threads.  This has nothing to do with scopes, or the GC, or any objects; all that matters is whether there are any foreground threads running.

Comment: Yeah, @Servy has provided a better explanation to your questions about garbage collection; this answer is more about "how do I change this unexpected behavior?"

Comment: My question did ask about garbage collection, but in my head I was trying to understand why the thread never terminated (I now know it is because it was running as a foreground thread).  The isBackground was my light bulb moment.

Answer (score 10):

> However, my understanding is that once a class is out of scope, its resources will eventually be tidied up by garbage collection.

This can be stated more precisely:

Once an object instance is no longer accessible from any executable code through a managed reference, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

When you create a new thread that is executing a particular object's method you're making that object's contents accessible throughout that thread's lifetime.  The GC can only clean it up if it's able to prove that it is no longer possible for any of the application's threads to ever access that object again.  Since your code *can* still access the object instance, it doesn't get GCed.

Answer (score 1):

Variable's scope is for the compiler to determine whether the variable is accessible by other methods. Thread is a running object that is controlled by the runtime.